# IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb due to error in the last update on support library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

After click update to update some android SDK packages, when i open android studio and try to run any application, that's what i get:

> IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb

And the details is the below:

[image: Error Details]

And in the Details tab:

```
Unable to locate adb
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DeployTargetPickerDialog.<init>(DeployTargetPickerDialog.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.ShowChooserTargetProvider.showPrompt(ShowChooserTargetProvider.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getDeployTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:475)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:294)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:158)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:55)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:118)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$300(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:67)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:509)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I report the error to google and i tried to uninstall and install all of: sdk-build-tools and sdk-platform-tools but the same error still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of investigation, this error happen due to uncompleted install of sdk-platform-tools while the last update and when i tried to uninstall it and reinstall it again from Android studio UI there is unexpected behaviour happened.

So the solution is to open the terminal in Android Studio and write the below command to install sdk-platform-tools:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter platform-tools
```

Comment: I solved it by removing and then reinstalling the **Android SDK Platform-Tools** from SDK Manager.